# Trying CameraX 1.1.0-beta02 on Emulator x86 API30 or x86_64 API31 causing android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am implementing a CameraActivity using CameraX with the current latest version 1.1.0-beta01 / 1.1.0-beta02.

But even with sample code from github (CameraXbasic) it is not working on the most recent Emulators for API 31 and API 32.
Is there any way to get this work?

```
2022-03-11 12:51:07.393 18491-18556/com.android.example.cameraxbasic E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: 
    android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2350)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1277)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:579)
        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl.close(SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl.java:464)
        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.CaptureSession.release(CaptureSession.java:418)
        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.releaseSession(Camera2CameraImpl.java:518)
        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.resetCaptureSession(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1201)
        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.closeCamera(Camera2CameraImpl.java:432)
        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.reopenCameraAfterError(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1665)
        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.handleErrorOnOpen(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1617)
        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.onError(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1593)
        at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.CameraDeviceStateCallbacks$ComboDeviceStateCallback.onError(CameraDeviceStateCallbacks.java:121)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.notifyError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1748)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.$r8$lambda$KBQCqQRdhVVn7uHI9Xdha6OqnsU(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.accept(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:281)
        at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:204)
        at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:111)
        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:231)
        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:173)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

Comment: windows? mac? linux? do you have a real camera attached?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Me too! Only on emulator. So strange.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Linux. Setting the camera to "emulated" instead of "virtualscene" fixes it for me. Issue also persists when using a webcam.